# How do I retain good connections with upper management if I do not intend to stay after my internship?

Tags: career-development

The graduate level, long term internship historically leads to full time employment.  I intend to look for work in a different location within the same field.  When asked directly about my future career intentions how do i diplomatically field questions by upper management who I want to retain connections with?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's less of a big deal for interns to move on than it  is for permanent employees.  Don't overthink this. Thank them for the opportunity to work with them and for all you've learned. Tell them you hope to stay in touch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Generally, the exact same way you'd respond if you *weren't* an intern and were just a regular employee seeking a job elsewhere.**  In other words, diplomatically and as far away from 'Here are all the reasons I'm not happy here' as possible.

You're not leaving because of reasons X, Y, and/or Z.  You're leaving because you got a great opportunity with Alternative Inc, where you'll get to do A, B, and C - and you're really excited about it.  You loved working with them at CurrentTech, but you feel the best move for your career development is with Alternative Inc, because you're going to get to learn L, M, and maybe N.  Etc.

If you're asked these questions *before* 'Alternative Inc' is lined up?  Then you're in the same boat as a regular employee that *intends* to quit but doesn't have another job yet: don't say anything at all.  Worst case... imagine that the end of your internship rolls around... but you can't find any companies willing to hire you for what you want to do.  You've already announced you don't want to stick around... but don't actually have a new job to go to.

If it helps, think of it this way: the higher-ups you're worried about care a heck of a lot *less* about this than you do.  Keep in mind, you leaving at the end of an internship is far less of a hassle than a longer-term employee quitting.  As long as you're respectful, professional, and courteous?  Then they're not going to have anything against you.

Comment: I have heard this advice echoed in the site before and it is good to hear it reaffirmed in my case.  It's conducive to talk about the positive reasons you're making a step towards something else rather than the negative reasons you're leaving or escaping something even if all related to the same action.